# How to Save Files inside a folder in the App Folder ? Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am able to take a picture and save it inside the Document folder, but I want to save those files to a folder called pictures inside the ****.app folder, not to the Document folder, otherwise my given paths for view pictures will not work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add your code snippet for saving and reading the photo files

Answer (score 3):

You can't write to the app's bundle - which is what you are trying to accomplish. The bundle folder is off limits.

You will need to resort to saving to **Documents** or **Documents/../Library/Caches**.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, Yes Thats true .... I found alternative way, which is just simply read it from the Document folder... It works ....!!!

Comment: OP stated that he found an alternative way. He should only accept the answer if it's the answer to the question. However, a helpful answer does merit an upvote.